# How do I bookmark sections in a PDF file converted from Libre Office?

Tags: libreoffice

I have an .odt document I have converted to .pdf, with many different sections, subsections, subsubsections, etc.. In the PDF I want to create a nice bookmark table to easily navigate the document.

The good part is the sections I need bookmarked are either bolded or italized which is different from all text of the document. Presently I'm bookmarking one by one which will take a number of hours but I have no idea where to look for a program to do this task or how to start with scripting this.

Even a program on Windows would help - I guessing it's against the rules to mention Windows, but by some off-chance something like this exists it would save me hours. I'm assuming it doesn't and the only way would have to be by way of a script into a pipe. So if anyone knows how to go about this it would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Use Headings!

You shouldn't be using bold and italics for the sections/subsections. Bold and italics *should* be used to **emphasize** text only.

To denote the different levels of the document, use headings. When you convert to PDF they will be autobookmarked for you.

### In LibreOffice:

To the left of the dropdown menu for fonts is a dropdown for applying different styles. Use `heading 1` for the highest level sections, `heading 2` for subsections, `heading 3` for subsubsections, etc.

You can modify the style of each of these headings easily by using the "Style and Formatting" toolbar. Press <kbd>F11</kbd>, find the style you wish to edit, right-click and select "modify".